# Is there a Drupal rating module that lets you rate from 1 - 10?

Tags: 7, rating

I'm looking for a Drupal module that will let me rate something on a scale of 1 - 10.

It doesn't look like the [Fivestar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fivestar) or [Rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/rate) module would allow that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Fivestar, despite its name, allows you to rate from 1 - 10. There's also a Rate module to do the same, but has a different architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [VotingAPI](https://www.drupal.org/project/votingapi) module (D6 and D7) offers a framework to developers of Drupal modules about voting and/or rating. It uses a standardized API and schema for storing, retrieving, and tabulating votes for Drupal content.

VotingAPI offers these key features:

- Create/Retrieve/Update/Delete operations for voting data.
- Whenever a vote is casted, it calculates the results and caches them. These calculations can either be the default calculations (average, total, etc), or they can be implemented via custom tallying functions.
- Via its integration with the **Actions** module, it can trigger workflow steps whenever votes are casted and results are tallied, such as promoting a node to the front page, hiding a comment flagged as spam, or sending some eMail.
- It integrates with the **Views** module, which allows for slice and dice of the content of a site based on user consensus. And tt provides functions to format vote data to display them to users.

**Rating related modules with a stable release for D7**:

- [Rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/rate) (D6 and D7).
- [Fivestar](https://drupal.org/project/fivestar) (D6 and D7).
- [Voting API Bayesian](https://drupal.org/project/votingapi_bayesian) (D7).
- [Star Rating](https://www.drupal.org/project/starrating) (D7, no [VotingAPI](https://www.drupal.org/project/votingapi) dependency).
- [Raty](https://www.drupal.org/project/raty) (D7-beta2).

**Other rating related modules**:

- [Plus 1](https://www.drupal.org/project/plus1) (D6 and D7-alfa2).
- [Vote Up/Down](https://www.drupal.org/project/vote_up_down) (D6 and D7-alfa1).
- [NodeReview](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodereview) (D6-beta1 and D7-dev).
- [Voting Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/voting_rules) (D6-beta2 and D7-alfa1).
- [Drupalit](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalit) (D6).
- [Decisions](https://www.drupal.org/project/decisions) (D6, unsupported).

**Rating related modules with maintenance/development status 'unknown'**:

- [Extra Voting Forms](https://www.drupal.org/project/extra_voting_forms).
- [UpDown](https://www.drupal.org/project/updown).
- [Drigg](https://www.drupal.org/project/drigg).
- [Node Moderation](https://www.drupal.org/project/nmoderation).
- [SimpleVote](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplevote).
- [MediumVote](https://www.drupal.org/project/mediumvote).
- [User Review](https://www.drupal.org/project/userreview).
- [Latest and Greatest](https://www.drupal.org/project/latestgreatest).
- [jRating](https://www.drupal.org/project/jrating).
- [Loves and Hates](https://www.drupal.org/project/lovehate).

Comment: Yes I was referring to D7

Comment: Thanks for confirming (and "accept"). Thought I'd add a few more to the list of possibilities ... and an indication about releases and stability. Hope it won't cost me downvotes (because of the outdated ones), I just wanted to create an inventory of those I'm aware of ...