# How to use user feedback from Webforms

Tags: webforms, search, rating

Say I want to ask the user to rate articles on usefulness from 1-10.

How can I apply that rating to weight calculations for future searches of the same issue/tags?

I would like the most useful articles to appear higher in the search results.

Answer (score 1):

Best using of any of below module to solve your query. I think as per your query, no any module for 1-10 rating. Hope these module help you to do same as you want.

1. [Star Rating](https://www.drupal.org/project/starrating)

> Star Rating is a simple module that provides star rating field and
>   display formatter using Drupal 7's Field Type API.

2. [Rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/rate)

> This module provides flexible voting widgets for nodes and comments.

3. [Fivestar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fivestar)

> The Fivestar voting module adds a clean, attractive voting widget to
>   nodes and comments and any entity.

Comment: I have update my question. @KrishnaMohan I have just suggest OP to use any of these modules. It's not correct or wrong way to suggest then pls update if any text needed or I'll delete from here & next tym I'll aware of these.

Comment: No no you are correct. I am sure Rate module can solve OP's query. :)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to my answer to the question about "[Is there a Drupal rating module that lets you rate from 1 - 10?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/162334/is-there-a-drupal-rating-module-that-lets-you-rate-from-1-10/162353#162353)" for an "inventory" of rating related modules.

Note that quite a few of these modules have the [VotingAPI](https://www.drupal.org/project/votingapi) module as a dependency.

To actually "*apply that rating to weight calculations for future searches*", you might consider including these rating results via an appropriate set of fields in a "View" that you'd created to display your search results, which you'd probably then also want to "sort" by the rating results (like 'highest rated' first).